# select an available device or choose a simulated device as the destination

Tags: xcode, sfml

i[Please select an available device or choose a simulated device as the destination.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCrLP.jpg).i have successfully built your SFML project in Xcode but are not seeing the window/console show up, there could be a few potential reasons for this issue

i try :
Verify that the code is creating and displaying the window correctly: Double-check your code to ensure that you are creating and displaying the SFML window correctly. Make sure you are calling the sf::RenderWindow::display() function after drawing/rendering your content.

Check for any errors or exceptions: Check the console output or Xcode's debug console for any error messages or exceptions that may be occurring. If there are any issues, they may provide clues about what could be causing the window not to appear.